# Loops homotopic relative to A

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $(X,A)$ be a pair of path-connected spaces, where $A\subset X$.

How do we see/prove that this statement is true?

> Two loops $\gamma_0,\gamma_1\in\pi_1(X,x_0)$ are homotopic relative to $A$ if and only if $\gamma_0^{-1}\gamma_1$ is represented by a loop in $A$.

Comment: I think "homotopy relative to $A$" is only defined for maps that already agree on $A$. The statement you make reminds to "Two curves $\gamma_0,\gamma_1:[0,1]\to X$ are homotopic relative to $\{0,1\}$ if and only if $\gamma_0^{-1}\gamma_1$ has trivial class in $\pi_1(X)$".

Comment: The normal usage of "homotopic relative to $A$" is when you're considering maps $X \to Y$ for some space $Y$, and want the homotopy to be stationary on $A$. Do you know what definition your source is using? My guess would be they're talking about equivalence classes in $\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$, *i.e.* the set of paths that start in $A$ and end in $x_0$, up to homotopy (through such paths)

Comment: @JoshuaHunt yes you are right. I am following Hatcher which uses the definition that you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take "relative to $A$" to mean equivalence classes in $\pi_1(X, A, x_0)$, that is paths $\gamma: I \to X$ with $\gamma(0) \in A$ and $\gamma(1) = x_0$ up to homotopy through other paths of the same form.

The result then isn't too difficult to see. Let $i: \pi_1(X, x_0) \to \pi_1(X, A, x_0)$ denote the inclusion.

In one direction, if $[i(\gamma_1)] = [i(\gamma_0)]$ then that means we have a homotopy $H: I \times I \to X$ from $\gamma_0$ to $\gamma_1$ with $H(0, -) \in A$ and $H(1, -) = x_0$. Hopefully if you draw a picture of the square that represents $H$ (as Hatcher often does in chapter 4), you can convince yourself that the path $H(0, -)$ (a path in $A$) is homotopic (as paths) to the composition of the other three sides of the square, namely $\gamma_0 \cdot c_{x_0} \cdot \gamma_1^{-1} \simeq \gamma_0 \gamma_1^{-1}$.

In the other direction, if we have $\gamma_0 \gamma_1^{-1} \simeq \eta$ as paths, with $\eta \in \pi_1(A, x_0)$, then we can homotope $i(\gamma_1)$ to $i(\gamma_0)$ by pre-concatenating with progressively longer segments of $\eta$. (*i.e.* at time $t$ we have the path $\eta|_{[t, 1]} \cdot \gamma_1$.) The start point of the path will change as we do this, but since $\eta \in \pi_1(A, x_0)$ the start point will never leave $A$, and so $[i(\gamma_0)] = [i(\gamma_1)]$ in $\pi_1(X, A, x_0)$.

This seems a little convoluted written down, but if you draw a couple of pictures hopefully it will seem a lot clearer! This check is all part of checking that the long exact sequence $$\ldots \to \pi_1(A, x_0) \to \pi_1(X, x_0) \to \pi_1(X, A, x_0) \to \ldots$$ is exact at $\pi_1(X, x_0)$, so should be dealt with early on in Hatcher's chapter 4.

Comment: And how does your first direction show that $\gamma_0^{-1}\gamma_1$ is homotopic to loop in $A$ at base point $x_0$ which is the actual question? Could you please elaborate, thank you in advance!